DBT 'dbt' is not recognized as an internal or external command when running from Task Scheduler
I'm trying to move my DBT orchestration from an old remote Windows server v2016 to a v2022. I have big limitations, starting from the fact that I'm working with DBT core and that I can't use any orchestration tool like dagster. So we made it run via the good old Task Scheduler on the v2016. On top of this the v2022 doesn't have internet access.
I overcome the challenge if installing a py virtualenv on the v2022, thanks mates Moving Python venv to another machine without internet
I can make my DBT models run manually via CMD, by simply

C:\py_pkgs\pkgs\venv\Scripts\activate
dbt run --profiles-dir C:\pathtoprofiles

This works perfectly.
However when running my imported tasks into Task Scheduler, from the v2016 to v2022, I'm getting

'dbt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

My config is:
Start a program > cmd
Add arguments (optional): /c "C:\py_pkgs\pkgs\venv\Scripts\activate & dbt run --profiles-dir C:\pathtoprofiles"
Start in (optional): C:\DBT_projects_folder
I run the task with highest privileges + with an admin service account - same as in v2016.
Any idea what could this be?
thanks for any help!
